# which recipe will be used first?

Tags: yocto, openembedded

If I have many recipes, ex:

```
dmidecode_1.0.bb
dmidecode_1.1.bb
dmidecode_git.bb
```

when I doing:

`CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL += "dmidecode"`

which recipe will be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bitbake -e dmidecode | grep -e "^PV="` will tell you.

The layer priority (`BBFILE_PRIORITY`) takes precedence, then `PV` which is dynamically set if you're getting the sources from git IIRC. There's also `DEFAULT_PREFERENCE` that can be set and modifies the logic behind version precedence.